# Pressing "v" in the terminal opens bash-fc.some_random_string in the editor

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, readline

Recently I've started using the vim keybinding in the terminal. I changed the keybinding of the
terminal by adding the following line in the ~/.bashrc file.

```
set -o vi
```

But I've noticed an issue with it. When I go to the normal mode by pressing the "Escape" key and then press "v" it opens a file with the following name in the default editor.

> /tmp/bash-fc.some_random_string_here

e.g., /tmp/bash-fc.PFb1Vy

I've tried checking all the terminal shortcuts but couldn't find anything with "v" there. Though I'm new to shell scripting, I checked the ~/.bashrc file but couldn't find anything related "bash-fc".

Could anyone of you kindly tell me what's the reason behind it? It's really annoying to accidentally open vim and quit vim every time :(

[image: In normal mode(after pressing Escape)]

[image: And I press "v" and I'm in vim :(]

Comment: Some additional information here: [What is 'v' key in bash vi-mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478275/what-is-v-key-in-bash-vi-mode)

Comment: In vim pressing the "v" key enters you into visual mode to select text. But in the terminal if I type something then go to normal mode by pressing "Escape" and then press "v" it takes whatever on that line and goes straight into vim and pastes it there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no visual mode** in Bash's Vi-mode. A <kbd>v</kbd> in normal mode dumps the current line in the user's preferred editor. One types/edits the command there and upon saving and quitting the editor (in Vim, `:x` or `:wq`), Bash issues the command.

**To disable the binding** you can rebind it to an unnoticeable operation. Just add this to the `~/.inputrc` file:

```
set keymap vi-command
"v":redraw-current-line
```

That file only affects GNU Readline (the library that handles user input in Bash), never the Vim editor itself.

---

At the present time, Vi-mode users dwell mostly on undocumented grounds (<kbd>v</kbd> is not in Bash's manual nor in [Readline's manual](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/readline-common/readline.3readline.en.html)) and face some bugs. For example, if you type

```
a b b
```

at the prompt, put the cursor on the `a` and then try `tb` in normal mode, the cursor will jump to the first `b`, but then if you try to repeat the movement with `;`, the cursor won't move.